# Get sub folder from document library using SharePoint.Client.dll

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, development, client-object-model, folder, csom

I need to get the folder named `Arshad` from SharePoint Document library folder.
The path of the sub folder is :

> `http://url/Shared Documents/Arshad`

I need to access the folder using SharePoint Client object model.

When I try accessing, it shows me an error :

> Couldn't find the path.

The following is my code:

```
    var list =  clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(MainFolderName)

If the variable `MainFolderName = "Shared Documents";` then I can access that folder and even add a new folder inside the "Shared Documents"

    var SPfolder = list.RootFolder;
    clientContext.Load(SPfolder);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    SPfolder = SPfolder.Folders.Add(FolderName);
```

Please help.

Comment: You are trying to get a folder, so why are you using a method designed to get a List?

Comment: How to get a folder then.? I thought list is a way to get the folder..!

Comment: A folder is a folder, a list is a list. See the first comment on this post for an example: http://andreaswijayablog.blogspot.se/2013/09/sharepoint-client-object-model-csom-get.html

Comment: tip: don't name your variables 'SP...' this creates confusing with the 'SharePoint Server Side object model'

Answer (score 7):

Folders are items as well. Just get the item and load the folder property.

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(Constants.SharePointUri))
{    
   var list = ctx.Site.RootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle(Constants.Lists.Event.Name);
   var item = list.GetItemById(eventId);
   ctx.Load(list, d => d.Title, d => d.RootFolder.Name, d => d.Id);
   ctx.Load(item, d => d.DisplayName, d => d.Folder, d => d["FileRef"]);
   ctx.ExecuteQuery();

   // use item.Folder here
}
```

You can also use relative url's. A popular similar function is this one:

```
private static Folder GetListItemFolder(ListItem listItem)
{
    var folderUrl = (string)listItem["FileDirRef"];
    var parentFolder = listItem.ParentList.ParentWeb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);
    listItem.Context.Load(parentFolder);
    listItem.Context.ExecuteQuery();
    return parentFolder;
}
```

To get folder by name you need the url containing the list and the name

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(Constants.SharePointUri))
{
   string folderName = "/MyList/aFolderName";  // watch out with spaces!!
   Web web = context.Web;
   List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList");
   Folder folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderName);                

   ctx .Load(context.Web);
   ctx .Load(list);
   ctx .Load(folder);               
   ctx .ExecuteQuery();
}
```

To get items out of a folder use a CAML query.

Comment: great , I have same thing but in different way pls check this question i posted -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49431968/how-do-i-get-all-list-of-sub-folders-in-sharepoint-site-using-c-sharp-code